# Problem date_time_picker >=2.0.0 is forbidden Flutter latest version

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm upgrading to Flutter 3.13.0 from 3.7.3. I get this error after `make pubget`:

> Because date_time_picker >=2.0.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and pos_2 depends on intl ^0.18.0, date_time_picker >=2.0.0 is forbidden.
> So, because pos_2 depends on date_time_picker ^2.1.0, version solving failed.

How can I fix it?